# Thread management in Jetty Server 9.3.X

Tags: jetty-9

I was wondering that How does Jetty Server calculates and manages Acceptor,selector and request thread and what is the correlation between them?

Answer (score 0):

Selectors / Acceptor are calculated based on below formula.

```
int selectorCount=selectors>0?selectors:Math.max(1,Math.min(4,Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()/2))
int selectorCount=acceptors=Math.max(1, Math.min(4,cores/8));
```